# error: 'CFLAGS' does not name a type

Tags: c++, makefile, cflags

This is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

And when I run a script, for example, this one (`ex3.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 10;
    int height = 72;

    printf("I am %d years old.\n", age);
    printf("I am %d inches tall.\n", height);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
$ g++ Makefile.c -o makefile
Makefile.c:1:1: error: 'CFLAGS' does not name a type
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
^g++     ex3.c   -o ex3
$
```

Comment: `g++ Makefile.c -o makefile` really?

Comment: You're confused.  The `makefile` is the script for building.  The `ex3.c` file is your program that needs to be compiled.  The *script* contains instructions for translating your source file into an executable.

Comment: And your make file should be called `Makefile`, not `Makefile.c`.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't compile the `makefile`.

Use the `make` utility instead.

Synonyms include `nmake` and `gmake`.

The makefile should be passed to the `make` program or build utility.